# Issue with int/input/print in homework

Tags: python, input, integer

This is a three part question that I am having issues with....

1. My output is not giving me the option to input my integer, it is printing "none" on the following line and skipping the option
2. Ending the file trigger is not working properly
3. counting the players that I have recorded data for....I honestly don't know where to start on counting inputs

--------------------My Output----------------------
You will be asked to enter players names and scores
When you have no more names, enter End

Enter Player's Name or End to exit program: Randy
Enter Randy 's golf score: 
None
------------------My Output END--------------------

### My code;

```
def main():
     #introduction to user explaining required information to be entered
     print("You will be asked to enter players names and scores")
     print("When you have no more names, enter End")

     #double blank space
     print("\n")

     #defined y/n
     anotherPlayer = "y"

     #define file path to save user input
     usersFile = open('golf.txt', 'w')

     #
     while anotherPlayer == "y":
         playerName = input("Enter Player's Name or End to exit program: ")
         score = int(input(print("Enter", playerName, "'s golf score: ")))
         usersFile.write(playerName + "," + str(score) + "\n")

         anotherPlayer = input("Is there another player? y / End: ")

     End = usersFile.close()

main()
```

-----------------end my code--------------------

I need it to say;

---------Assignment output Needed-----------------

You will be asked to enter players names and scores
When you have no more names, enter End

Enter Player's Name or End to exit program: Randy
Enter Randy 's golf score: 50

Enter Player's Name or End to exit program: End
You have written 1 players records to golf.txt

---------End assignment output----------------

Comment: please fix indentation in your code

Comment: I think i did it properly y or n?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def main():
    # introduction to user explaining required information to be entered
    print("You will be asked to enter players names and scores")
    print("When you have no more names, enter End")

    # double blank space
    print("\n")

    # defined y/n
    anotherPlayer = "y"

    # define file path to save user input
    usersFile = open('golf.txt', 'w')

    #
    while anotherPlayer == "y":
        playerName = raw_input("Enter Player's Name or End to exit program: ")
        score=input("Enter "+ str(playerName)+"'s golf score: ")
        usersFile.write(playerName + "," + str(score) + "\n")

        anotherPlayer = raw_input("Is there another player? y / End: ")

    End = usersFile.close()


main()
```

Comment: other answers are also telling the same thing

Comment: other answers didnt have the playerName as a string as you did...... which is what was making the thing go bonkers

Answer (score 0):

```
score = int(input(print("Enter", playerName, "'s golf score: ")))
```

Should be changed to

```
score = int(input("Enter {0}'s golf score: ".format(playerName)))
```

for opening and closing a file in python the efficient method is as follows:

```
with open("filename", "w") as userFile:
    userFile.write(data)
```

using the with open method will close the file for you when the loop is complete.

Comment: You will be asked to enter players names and scores
When you have no more names, enter End


Enter Player's Name or End to exit program: Randy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Software Design\Unit 4\Gossard Unit 4.py", line 27, in <module>
    main()
  File "G:\Software Design\Unit 4\Gossard Unit 4.py", line 18, in main
    score = int(input("Enter", playerName,"'s golf score: "))
TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 3

Comment: I have tried that multiple times and the only way I can get the players name to go in is with "print"

Comment: I see I missed a big part of that, input only takes one argument. look at my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `print` here.

```
score = int(input(print("Enter", playerName, "'s golf score: ")))
```

Use this

```
score = int(input("Enter {}'s golf score: ".format(playerName)))
```

Comment: When I remove print I get this error

Traceback (most recent call last): File "G:\Software Design\Unit 4\Gossard Unit 4.py", line 27, in <module> main() File "G:\Software Design\Unit 4\Gossard Unit 4.py", line 18, in main score = int(input("Enter", playerName,"'s golf score: ")) TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 3

Comment: It's not just removing the print statement, read the code again.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in the line

```
score = int(input(print("Enter", playerName, "'s golf score: ")))
```

You cant put a print function inside the input function and you also can not do it like this:

```
score = int(input("Enter", playerName, "'s golf score: "))
```

Because `input` does not work the same way `print` does. You should read about [formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) in python and do it like this:

```
score = int(input("Enter {0}'s golf score: ".format(playerName)))
```